# Does calling data() on a document has computational cost when using Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When retrieving a document from Firestore database, you are required to call the data() method of such document to retrieve the payload.

I wonder if there are any computational costs of doing so that would require your code to be written to call it only once like this:

```
db.collection('documents').doc('0001').get()
    .then(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        let a = data.a;
        let b = data.b;
        let c = data.c;    
    });
```

instead of this:

```
db.collection('documents').doc('0001').get()
    .then(doc => {
        let a = doc.data().a;
        let b = doc.data().b;
        let c = doc.data().c;
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, if the code works for you, there is not a "requirement" to change anything.  Don't prematurely optimize if you don't need to.  That said, it's obviously less efficient to call a method three times if just one call would suffice.

If you want to see what data() does, you can [look directly at the source code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/76afbb649ef77133361b20d4a8e6522abfa039c8/src/document.js#L440).  You can see that it's building a new object with each call, and populates that with the fields from the document.  If you're fine with 3x the memory and compute costs than minimally required, then there's no problem.

Comment: Ok, this answers the question. My concern was about some kind of lazy database loading triggered by data() but it is not the case. thanks!

Comment: If there was any lazy loading, that would have made data() potentially asynchronous, and it would have to return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a difference in terms of computational cost: after the promise has resolved (so when you are in the then) you have got a "doc" object and you are disconnected from the database. The two approaches you mention to get a, b and c are very similar in terms of computational cost (the difference is neglectable).

Comment: The OP is asking about the repeated calls to doc.data() rather than a single call.  It's not about the use of a promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson do you think it would make a significant difference to call doc.data() three times instead of one, in this specific case?